# Как вставить карту самоизоляции на сайт

Tags: html, карты

Яндекс создал карту самоизоляции https://yandex.ru/web-maps/covid19/isolation?ll=41.775580%2C54.894027&z=3 Можно ли как-то вставить её на сайт?

Comment: Там в меню справа (три полоски), есть пункт Поделиться, в нем "Код для вставки на сайт", в котором (неожиданно), код для вставки на сайт `<div style="position:relative;o....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это просто ссылка.
По идее можно вставить блок этой карты на сайт:

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/web-maps?utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:0px;">
        Яндекс.Карты
    </a>
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/web-maps/covid19/isolation?ll=41.775580%2C54.894027&utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps&z=3" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:14px;">
        Индекс самоизоляции
    </a>
    <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/web-maps/covid19?embed=covid-map" width="560" height="400" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true" style="position:relative;"></iframe>
</div>
```